# find() jquery access to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to access to more than one element of my document by using find() jquery function.

When i call

```
$(document).find('.myclass')
```

I get all the elements but how can i access them specifically ?

I mean, if i want to edit the first element of the list like this

```
$(document).find('.myclass')[0].css('top', '20px');
```

It don't work, because it's only code and not the object..

What is the best way to edit specifically one object of the find() return ?

Comment: It's *well* worth your time to set aside an hour or two and read [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It really only takes that long, and it repays that time *tremendously*.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/find/ Yeah i already read this page, but there is only exemples with one result on the find...

Comment: But I'm going to take your advice. Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you access an item using `[idx]`, you are getting back the DOM object, not a jQuery object. If you want to access the by index and still have a jQuery object, you can use `.eq()`:

```
$(document).find('.myclass').eq(0).css('top', '20px');
```

Since index 0 is the first element, if that's all you're going for, you could also use `.first()`:

```
$(document).find('.myclass').first()
```

or

```
$(document).find('.myclass:first')
```

You can also iterate them using `.each()`:

```
$(document).find('.myclass').each(function() {
    console.log(this); //logs current item (the element, not a jQuery object)
});
```

Comment: @ Jason: Probably worth explaining that `this` within the `each` iterator function is not a jQuery object, whereas the result of `eq`, `first`, etc. is. Possibly also worth discussing `[]` (direct access to the DOM object).

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('.myclass').first();
$('.myclass').last();
$('.myclass').eq(2); // the third element (first element is 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

USe `.eq()`

```
$(document).find('.myclass').eq(0).css('top', '20px');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not even need a find.Just quite simply

```
$('.myclass').first().css('top', '20px');
```